# When Saving a wicked_pdf PDF file to active storage, the pdf is corrupted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf

I want to save the generated PDF as an Active Storage attachement.

```
pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
      render_to_string(pdf: 'SurveyReportForm', template: '/screenings/test', layout: 'pdf',  formats: :pdf)
     )

 
@screening.report.attach(
  io: StringIO.new(pdf),
  filename: "#{@screening.id}-report",
  content_type: 'application/pdf'
)
```

The code runs without errors.  However when I then click the link to view the pdf

```
 <%= link_to "Download Report", rails_blob_path(@screening.report, disposition: "attachment") %>
```

I get a pdf that has what looks like pdf binary/source code  on the page, starting with:

```
%PDF-1.4 1 0 obj << /Title (þÿ) /Creator (þÿwkhtmltopdf 0.12.6) /Producer (þÿQt 4.8.7...
```

What has gone wrong?  How can I debug this to work out if the problem is in pdf generation or how I'm saving it and how can I fix it?

Comment: Try giving the file a pdf extension. filename: "#{@screening.id}-report.pdf"

Comment: unfortunately no.  It opens as 3-report-7.pdf with the pdf code showing either way

Comment: what happens if you save the pdf to a local file and open it?

Comment: this is just in dev environment so it stores to /storage - if i open it by going to it in finder and opening in eg preview it's the same

Comment: you can write the file after you generate it  File.write("foo.pdf", pdf) and see what it looks like before you stick it in storage

Comment: @KJ - i don't completly understand your comment.  are you saying there is some illegal text in my templates or something?

Comment: so if i'm following correctly the problem is in the pdf creation not in the attachment to activeStoreage.   Ill simplify the layout to see if its something in the templates.  I had this pdf previously working as a direct view from the action but getting it to save as a pdf has proved much harder.

Comment: ok, thank you.  so ill look at replacing the StringIO.new(pdf) section.

Comment: @debugger If i try to write out the pdf to file as suggested I get Encoding::UndefinedConversionError  ""\xFE" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8"

Comment: This still isnt working.  I can render the same templates out as a pdf and it works fine.  if i add save_to_file option it saves fine.  but if i try to create the pdf and attach or save it manually it save as corrupted / just shows the binary code in the pdf.  any recommendations to debug welcome

Answer (score 0):

The issue isn't with ActiveStorage, but with the download not being served with the correct Mime type for a PDF. Because you aren't specifying it, it is being served as `text/plain` instead of `application/pdf`.

I think you might be able to change this by registering a PDF Mime type, like the WickedPDF README tells you:

```
Mime::Type.register "application/pdf", :pdf
```

This should instruct Rails to know that when serving a PDF, to serve it with that mime type.

Otherwise, you could create a controller endpoint to download the PDF like this:

```rb
def download
  send_file rails_blob_path(@screening.report),
    disposition: "attachment",
    content_type: "application/pdf"
end

# or

def download
  pdf = # retrieve PDF contents
  send_data pdf, filename: "mypdf.pdf",
    disposition: "attachment",
    content_type: "applicaton/pdf"
end
```